# how to keep an updated development release in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

I am not sure how I can maintain in GitLab a development version, i.e. a section where beta testers can download binaries). So far, i came up with the following approach (I did not test it yet):

Create or update a tag "dev" and manually add the binaries via the following steps:

```
   1) git push origin :refs/tags/dev
   2) git tag -fa dev
   3) git push origin master --tags
   4) manually update binaries
```

Is it the way to go?  Before to implement this approach I would like to check if there are official/recommended approach

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This doesn't really have much to do with git, does it? But sounds to me like a job for GitLab's CI/CD pipelines.

Comment: No indeed it is a GitLab topic but I did not refer to Git in my question. Otherwise, maybe it is something that can be solved by CI/CD but I am really not sure. Thank you for your reply anyway.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I saw now that you didn't add the _git_ tag yourself...

Comment: Oh, I see, so I removed that git tag that was incorrectly added. I also post the same questions on GitLab support forum.